# Rake Task w/ ActionMailer - Undefined Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, actionmailer, rake-task

I have a custom rake task and I am using a mailer with this task. I have an agent table with all of an agent's info. I also have an agent_card table that houses all of their license data. The agent_card table also has an agent_id column to identify which card goes with which agent. When trying to run the rake task and send out the mailer, I keep getting "ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass." I can't figure out how to get the name, email, and phone through the agent_card table. I have included all the code below. Please and thank you!

Error:

```
rake aborted!
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/Code/app/views/license_expire_mailer/license_expi re_mgr.html.erb:7:in   `_app_views_license_expire_mailer_license_expire_mgr_html_erb___944550213720770297_70323524541360'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:904:in `block in collect_responses'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:918:in `each'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:918:in `each_template'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:900:in `collect_responses'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:829:in `mail'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/Code/app/mailers/license_expire_mailer.rb:14:in `license_expire_mgr'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:596:in `block in process'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:593:in `process'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:584:in `initialize'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `new'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `__getobj__'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:34:in `message'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionmailer-4.2.6/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/Code/lib/tasks/license_expiration.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/Code/lib/tasks/license_expiration.rake:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/michaelwiesenhart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Agent Model:

```
has_one :agent_card
```

AgentCard Model:

```
belongs_to :agent
```

license_expire_mgr.html.erb

```
Hiya, <br><br>

The agent listed below has a license that will expire one week from today. Please make sure they renew before it expires!<br><br>

<strong>Name:</strong> <%= @agent.name %><br>
<strong>Phone:</strong> <%= @agent.phone %><br>
<strong>Email:</strong> <%= @agent.email %><br><br>
```

license_expire_mailer.rb

```
class LicenseExpireMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default from: "Mike <help@mike.com>"

   def license_expire_mgr(agent_card, agent)
   @agent_cards = agent_card
   @agent = agent
   mail to: "mike@mike.com", subject: "Agent License Expiring"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to use agent_card and didn't need it. Once I removed it, it works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

`@agent` is not being passed through to the mailer or the value of it is being evaluated as `nil`.

The problem is not with your rake task or your mailer, figure out why the param is `nil` and that will solve your problem.

Comment: I am not sure why it is nil. There is def an agent associated with the agent_card. I dropped the DB, restored from a backup. I don't know.

Comment: You have to check the value of the agent, It must be nil in that case.

Comment: @BIlalKhan I guess that is what I am asking...how would I do that?